# Configure two NGINX with same domain but different servers and context

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Is it possible to configure two different NGINX on different servers with the same domain but each will have different context. Let me give you more information. I have an existing NGINX that is server a production environment; for example

```
mydomain.com/prod
```

I want to create

```
mydomain.com/dev
```

but I don't want to change the NGINX conf on prod environment. I will spin up a dev environment with a new NGINX server but using the same domain but have the location redirect to /dev

Answer (score 0):

After some research, this is actually not a recommended approach.

Comment: Please share the recommended approach of using one domain forwarding to multiple services.